# Android app Stops and starts on its own

Tags: android, eclipse

Can anyone help with my android app. I am using eclipse and it is a lengthy page app. At page 18 is tells me that it stopped unexpectedly but after you hit the force close button it starts at the same place and it works correctly.
It is a simple quiz app with back and next buttons. This is the only button that wont work on the first try but as I said after you hit force close the app starts up at the same place and the button works just fine. Then you can also go back and forth over that same page without a problem...what gives?

Answer (score 0):

user1009028, we need more information to be able to know for sure what is going on.

Sometimes, for mysterious reasons, the app seems to "crash" and yet still run. There are a number of possibilities here.

If you can post your full code online somewhere, that is great, but even just the logcat will be useful. Since you know how to reproduce the error, get to the page just before the crash, clear your logcat, then go to the next page so it crashes. Then copy and paste everything in your logcat to here in Stack Overflow; that will be the most relevant information related to the crash, which may or may not give enough detail--at least we'll know what to ask for then :)

Regarding your question on "com.csg.SlideNineteen@405761f8", the default toString on objects gives the class name and its address in memory. The numbers at the end are the address of the object in memory... not very useful in most cases.

Comment: I am guessing I hane too many activities. I just used a new activity each time I changed pages. I have a simple 26 page quiz app that has back and next buttons on each page. I created a different xml and java class for each page using the image as the background to use it as a sort of powerpoint feel when you advance the page. How can I combine activities and still be able to use multiple images? I will also try to get info from locat but I am pretty sure thats what it is.

Comment: Well, using 26 activities is probably not the best way to go, true. If the user kept pressing "back" they would have to press it 26 times to leave the app (unless you override the back key functionality, of course). You can use one activity and then just change your content. Get a reference to your ImageView (or whatever you're using) and programmatically change it... I'm afraid it's really hard to be specific without knowing more about what you're doing or seeing the code.